# Packages in MatLab for a beginner?

Tags: matlab, modeling

I need MatLab for 2D and 3D modeling.

I have little experience in MatLab.
Which packages should I study first to learn modeling in MatLab?

Comment: What do you mean by 2d and 3d modeling?  Are you developing the models elsewhere, and doing analysis in MATLAB?  Are you doing visualization, FEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Virtual Reality Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/vr/vr_product_page.html)?